# Mobile dropdown menu not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Code: http://pastebin.com/dw2XT82f

When the screen gets to the point where the navbar get condensed into the mobile version the dropdown box is not working.

Any idea why?

Comment: Seems to only be coded for hover and not for touch events.

Comment: When I add code for the click it still does not work.

Comment: You just have the wrong `data-target` value. That should be the id of the drop-down target.

Comment: @user1448063 Just to add some tips to help you, if you are using `bootstrap` be sure to always check the `id`s used. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this code right here? Around line 115.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

replace the `data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"` to `data-target="#oit-navbar"`.

Your drop down doesnt work beacause it is calling the wrong `id` for the dropdown target. Hope it helps.